# Python pandas group by and eliminate

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| es | ss | cc |
|  | bc | cc |
| ty | bc | cc |
| gz | gis | cc |
|  | ss | cc |
| gz | gis | cc |

Hi,

Have a dataframe df as shown above, the expected output is if repetition of item in column b for which column a is empty then output would be b + c   else a + b + c

expected output to a new column should be:

| cleaned |
| --- |
| sscc |
| bccc |
| gzgiscc |

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
#import numpy as np

df=df.reset_index().drop_duplicates(subset=['b'])
m=df['a'].duplicated(keep=False)
out=pd.DataFrame(np.where(m,df['b']+df['c'],df['a']+df['b']+df['c']),columns=['cleaned'])
```

output of `out`:

```
    cleaned
0   sscc
1   bccc
2   gzgiscc
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope  I've understood your question right:

```py
x = (
    df.sort_values(by=["a"])
    .drop_duplicates("b", keep="first")
    .sum(axis=1)
    .to_frame("cleaned")
)
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
   cleaned
1     bccc
4     sscc
3  gzgiscc
```